# Using user input to call a function from a class

Tags: python, class, input

I am trying to call a function from a class based on user input. I've tried other examples based on this but keep on getting various errors depending on which direction I try it.

The test code that I am using is

```
    def one():
         print('one hahah')

    def two():
        print('two hahah')

    def the_count():
        print('I am the count who likes to count')


    dispatcher = {
        'one': one, 'two': two, 'three': the_count
    }

action = input('Option: - ')

jo.dispatcher[action]()
```

There we have what I want, but once I added the **self** argument things stopped working properly.
Here is my actual code...

```
import math
class femblem(object):



    def j(self):
    print('hi')
    `data goes here`

...

    def __init__(self,lv,name):
        self.lv = lv
        self.name = name

    dispatcher = {
        'j': j(self)
        }



action = input('Character: - ')        
unit1 = femblem(5,"joshua")
unit1.dispatcher[action]()
```

returns **NameError: name 'self' is not defined**
if I take out **self** it gives me an error saying that it needs that for an argument (which it does).
Not very experienced in python, any ideas why this isnt working?
Thanks

Comment: You are calling the function in the definition of the dispatcher. You should assign the values to just the function like you did in the first example.

Comment: it is better to use `getattr` when working with classes, since the method is already stored in the dictionary of the class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could approach this problem, one of which would be to make `dispatcher` an instance method of the class:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self,lv,name):
         self.lv = lv
         self.name = name
     def one(self):
         print('this is one!')
     def dispatcher(self, action):
         d = {'one':self.one}
         return d[action]
```

Then you get something like:

```
>>> f = Foo(5, 'Joshua')
>>> action = input()
>>> f.dispatcher(action)()
'this is one!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, your class will act like a dict here, and *your instance is the dispatcher* so just use `getattr` and the `self` [magic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) will work:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def bar(self):
...       return 42
...    def baz(self):
...       return 88
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> getattr(foo, 'bar')()
42
>>> getattr(foo, 'baz')()
88
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what you are trying to do, but this snippet dispatches to the respective functions defined in your dispatcher for the user inputs `one`, `two` and `three`:

```py
class femblem:
    def __init__(self, lv, name):
        self.lv = lv
        self.name = name

    def one(self):
        print('one hahah')

    def two(self):
        print('two hahah')

    def the_count(self):
        print('I am the count who likes to count')

    @property
    def dispatcher(self):
        return {
            'one': self.one, 
            'two': self.two, 
            'three': self.the_count
        }


action = input('Character: - ')        
unit1 = femblem(5, "joshua")
unit1.dispatcher[action]()
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer with `getattr` inside the class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        print('this is foo')

    def dispatcher(self):
        att = input('put some input: ')
        getattr(self, att)()

ob = Foo()
ob.dispatcher()
```